# Where can I find a complete list of Census Bureau Summary Level (SUMLEV) definitions in table format?

Tags: us-census

The Census Bureau published summary level (SUMLEV) definitions in PDFs, though these are not always complete and do not always match the SUMLEVs in the actual data file.

For example, [this PDF here](http://www.census.gov/prod/cen2010/doc/sf1.pdf) has the summary level sequence chart, but I cannot easily turn this information into a table. What I want is an EXCEL or text file with this information, NOT an image or PDF, like we see below.

Anyone find one?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page [Missouri Census Data Center - Census Geography and Summary Levels](http://mcdc.missouri.edu/allabout/sumlevs/) has a link to a listing of all the sumlev codes known to them as a [text file](http://mcdc2.missouri.edu/cgi-bin/browse?/pub/sasfmats/Ssumlev.sas@).

Although the text file is a SAS source code file it would be trivial to edit out the code before and after the list, and edit the rest to csv.

It's unclear what the license is for their text version of the list.